# ruby code will not render in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a really weird problem.  For some reason, when I use the .each method, the list generated will not appear in internet explorer.  It works perfectly in chrome, firefox, and safari though.  For example, here is one of the pages:

```
<% @skill_list.each do |skill| %>
    <tr>
        <td class=""><%= skill %></td>
        <td class="td60">
            <div class="buttons">
                <%= link_to "", skill_path(skill), :class => "button-delete", :method => :delete, :remote => true, data: {:confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete?" } %>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

And here is the controller that generates @skill_list as seen above:

```
def new
  if current_user.profile
    @skill_list = current_user.profile.tag_list
  end
end
```

The page renders perfectly in all the major browsers except internet explorer.  What's also weird is that the page itself renders, just nothing inside the .each.    It is not the only page I have that works in all browsers except internet explorer.  Almost all the pages I have that use .each to iterate do not work in internet explorer.  Does anyone have any ideas?  The pages are rendered via ajax, could it have anything to do with that?  Due to the nature of the site, the pages have to be rendered via ajax.

Comment: View the generated HTML to make sure it appears correctly.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with RoR. Would you please do “View source” in any browser and post the result for the generated table here.

Comment: are you properly loged in on IE? i see you check for current_user before creating the skill_list. make sure you are loged in